# Android: Javascript in webview that returns clicked position on an image?

Tags: javascript, android, image, webview

I use WebView to display an image, the image is large so there is scroll, also zooms, I am looking for a way to detect the location of user clicks/touches on the image, can anyone show me the Javascript for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/